# How do I automatically select a category in wordpress using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to select a wordpress category "Announcement" in a post form automatically using javascript.

When I inspect the input box, here is the code.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_937_1-checkbox-1-1538849482" 
name="category[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt- 
id="cred_form_937_1_cred_form_937_1-checkbox-1-1538849482" data-wpt- 
name="category[]" value="3" data-parent="-1" data-value="Announcement" 
class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
```

Edit: The form generates a new sequence in the ID, what stays the same is cred_form_937_1-checkbox-1-, but the rest changes. Can I use another variable? Preferably the "data-value" element.

I have tried the following, but it does not work.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel- 
core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
<script>
var input = document.getElementById('cred_form_937_1-checkbox-1- 
1538849482');
input.focus();
input.select();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery( '#cred_form_937_1-checkbox-1-1538849482' ).prop('checked', 
true);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and the data-value to get the input like this:

```
var input = $('*[data-value="Announcement"]');
```